# How to use JNI to start JVM in builder C++ application

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface, c++builder

So i need to use jni to call java method.
i started with this code :

```
JNIEnv *env1;
JavaVM**  jvm1;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args1;
JavaVMOption options1[1];
options1[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=D:\\Java Src\\TestStruct"; //Path to the java source code
vm_args1.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
vm_args1.nOptions = 1;
vm_args1.options = options1;
vm_args1.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

int reAt = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm1, (void**)&env1, &vm_args1);
if(reAt < 0)
    Label1->Caption = "failed";
else
    Label1->Caption = "Success";
```

I convert jvm.lib to OMF lib for to use in my builder C++ Application :

```
 COFF2OMF jvm.lib jvm2.lib
```

I added jvm2.lib to the library path  to fixe link error about JNI_CreateJavaVM function.

Now my application compile without error.

But it crash when it call JNI_CreateJavaVM function.

I added the jvm.dll near my .exe

What is the pb in there steps??

How can fixe it?

Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [use JNI to start JVM Builder C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550578/use-jni-to-start-jvm-builder-c)

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `JNI_CreateJavaVM` should be a valid pointer to `JavaVM*`:

```
JavaVM* jvm1;
int reAt = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm1, ...);
```

In your example, `jvm1` is uninitialized.

Consult [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) for details.