# use JNI to start JVM Builder C++

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, c++builder

in this post [How to use JNI to start JVM in builder C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548699/how-to-use-jni-to-start-jvm-in-builder-c-application/25549109?noredirect=1#comment39894205_25549109) i converted jvm.lib from Coff to Omf. i used it to link JNI_CreateJavaVM() function. But it crash .

I used another code to start JVM from Builder C++ application. When i load the jvm.dll. It work!! the JVM is created when i load jvm in java directory but not when i copy this file(jvm.dll) in another directory and call it from this directory.Can you explain why i can't use a copy of jvm.dll to creat my JVM?

This is my Code :

```
JNIEnv *env;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
JavaVMOption options;
memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));

options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.;tika-app-1.5.jar;";
jint ii = GetVersion();

vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = &options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
//String strPath = "C:\\Users\\mhechkel\\Documents\\RAD Studio\\Projects\\TestJVM\\Win32\\Debug\\jvm.dll";  
// when i copy jvm.dll in my application folder: It dosn't work!!!
String strPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_65\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll";

HMODULE jvm_dll = LoadLibrary(strPath.c_str()); //here it work fine!!

/// You might check the GetLastError() here after the LoadLibrary()
if(jvm_dll == NULL) 
{    
    Label1->Caption = "can't load dll"; 
}

 JNI_CreateJavaVM_ptr = (JNI_CreateJavaVM_func)GetProcAddress(jvm_dll, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

 /// You might check the GetLastError() here
 if(JNI_CreateJavaVM_ptr == NULL)
 {
      Label1->Caption = "can't load function";
 }

 int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM_ptr(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
 if(ret < 0)
 {
    Label1->Caption = "Unable to Launch JVM\n";
 }
 return env;
```

Comment: in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989502/jni-createjavavm-exit-code-1 and in the ansewer n°1 he say it sould be the jvm in the ProgramFile\java\ director..  1- Add the place where jvm.dll lies (should be in the program files\java\jsdk_*\bin\server) to the PATH environment variable on your windows machine.. IS This RIGHT??!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the complete JRE in order to create Java VM.
JVM will not start if does not find matching JRE at the place relative to `jvm.dll` path.

On Windows you can override the path where JVM looks for JRE using `_ALT_JAVA_HOME_DIR` environment variable, though this is a HotSpot internal option and is not guaranteed to work.